# Return all objects that are referenced exactly twice by a related model

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have the following models:

```
class Person(...):
    name = CharField(...)

class Address(...):
    person = ForeignKey(Person)
    address = CharField(...)
```

I need to select all persons that have exactly two addresses.

So if my Address table looks like this:

```
----------------------------
| id | person_id | address |
----------------------------
| 1  | 1         | xyz     |
| 2  | 1         | xyz     |
| 3  | 2         | xyz     |
| 4  | 3         | xyz     |
| 5  | 3         | xyz     |
| 6  | 4         | xyz     |
| 7  | 5         | xyz     |
| 8  | 5         | xyz     |
| 9  | 5         | xyz     |
----------------------------
```

The resulting queryset should be

```
<QuerySet [<Person: 1>, <Person: 3>]>
```

I tried a lot, but just don't seem to get it right. I would be glad for a quick fix.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on Stack Overflow, you've granted a non-revocable right for SO to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). By SO policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [`annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/):

```
from django.db.models import Count
Person.objects.annotate(address_count=Count('address')).filter(
address_count=2)
```

Comment: @Daniel check updates. Also do you use related_name? It should be related_name value in this case.

Comment: @neverwalkaloner where do you see that `Person` model has an `address` field ?

Comment: @albar I dont see. From django docs related_query_name: It defaults to the value of related_name or default_related_name if set, otherwise it defaults to the name of the model.  So Default is model_name,  address in our case.

Comment: It's best to define your own related_name (improves code readability), I would update the `Address` model to have `person = ForeignKey(Person, related_name='addresses')` then you can use the person instance field `my_person.addresses` to get their addresses.